# What does using "{}" mean, in this context?

Tags: java

I found this line very confusing:

```
return new int[] {};
```

Are the two curly brackets referencing something in memory? Here's the full code:

```
class Solution {
    public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> prevMap = new HashMap<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            int num = nums[i];
            int diff = target - num; //En diff, iremos restando el num al Objetivo

            if (prevMap.containsKey(diff)) { 
                return new int[] { prevMap.get(diff), i };
            }

            prevMap.put(num, i);
        }

        return new int[] {};
    }
}
```

Comment: That's just the shortcuts syntax [to create an array](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html). An empty array in this case. And `new int[] {1, 2, 3}` would create an array containing those 3 integers.

Comment: Aah thanks so much @OHGODSPIDERS , kinda figured it out after asking lmao but understood perfectly now!

Answer (score 0):

It simply returns an empty `int` array as function output.

Comment: No, it returns an empty `int` array. Not an `Integer` array.

Comment: Thanks! I thought it had something to do with the prevMap variable, but turns out it was a lot simpler... smh